# Query Execution Time in Jena Fuseki

Tags: jena, fuseki

Is there a way to get the query execution time for SPARQL queries running in Jena Fuseki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your fuseki print out, you will see:

```
13:03:59 INFO  [1] Query = XXX
13:04:00 INFO  [1] exec/select
13:04:00 INFO  [1] 200 OK (467 ms)
```

The last line (467 ms) is the execution time

Answer (score 1):

The log file has start and store entries with timestamps, and the last entry of a request is the time taken.